# Did Alexander the Great change the meaning of "Hellenes"?

Tags: greek, meaning, language-evolution, history

The Hellenistic era was launched by Alexander the Great, and his death is usually defined as the starting point.
The Greek word *Hellenes* (*Ἕλληνες*) was in use before, during, and after the Hellenistic era as far as I can tell.
I wonder whether Alexander's conquests and the onset of the Hellenistic era had an effect on the meaning of the Greek word itself.
Was there a change in meaning from the time before Alexander to the time after him in the meaning of *Ἕλληνες* or related words?

Comment: This is a very interesting question and I hope a more erudite scholar will be able to answer it in detail. My impression was always that the "real" Greeks in Philip's time considered the Macedonians to be *not Greek at all*, being too tribal to be worth consideration. That fits Alexander into the same pattern as Napoleon (who was not French) and Hitler (who was not German).

Comment: cf. "from Hesiod the name of Hellenes then became the customary name for all Greeks." Gschnitzer, Fritz (Heidelberg), “Hellas”, in: Brill’s New Pauly.